# Minimum number of dimension

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $\vec{x}(t)$ solves the ODE $\dot{\vec{x}}= A\vec{x}$, with $A$ being an $n\times n$ matrix, and its first coordinate is $x_1(t)=5t^2\cos(3t)+2\sin(3t)-e^{2t}\sin(3t)+4t.$ What is the minimum number of dimension $n$?

I don't know where to start with this problem. Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am going to give you a hint, because you don't show any prior work. $\vec{x}_1^{\prime} = A_1 \vec{x}$, where $A_1$ is the first row of $A$. You know what $\vec{x}_1$ is, so you can compare the left hand side to the right hand side and see to what degree they match.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If the minimal polynomial of $\ A\ $ is $\ x^m+\sum_\limits{j=0}^{m-1}a_j x^j\ $, then
\begin{align}
0&=\left(A^m+\sum_\limits{j=0}^{m-1}a_j A^j\ \right)x\\
&=x^{(m)}+ \sum_\limits{j=0}^{m-1}a_j x^{(j)}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, every component of $\ x\ $, including $\ x_1\ $ must satisfy this $\ m$-th order linear differential equation.  What form does the solution of this differential equation have if the minimal polynomial has the factorisation $\ \prod_ \limits{j=0}^m\left(x-\lambda_j\right)\ $?