# minimum number of dimension so that $x'=Ax$ is satisfied for the given condition

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.
> Suppose $x(t)$ solves the equation $x'=Ax$ and its first coordinate is $x_1(t)=5t^2\cos(3t)+2\sin(3t)-e^{2t}\sin(3t)+4t$.
> What is the minimum number of dimension $n$?

I really don't see a way to handle this problem. When we compute the derivate of this first component it will be $$x_1'(t)=10t\cos(3t)-15t^2\sin(3t)+6\cos(3t)-2e^{2t}\sin(3t)-3e^{2t}\cos(3t)+4$$

Then what we have can be written as:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
10t\cos(3t)-15t^2\sin(3t)+6\cos(3t)-2e^{2t}\sin(3t)-3e^{2t}\cos(3t)+4\\ 
\cdot\\ 
\cdot\\
\cdot
\end{pmatrix}=$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \cdot&\cdot  &\cdot \\ 
 \cdot&\text{Matrix A}  &\cdot \\ 
 \cdot&\cdot  & \cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot  & \cdot
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
5t^2\cos(3t)+2\sin(3t)-e^{2t}\sin(3t)+4t\\ 
\cdot\\ 
\cdot\\
\cdot\\
\cdot 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So by comparing  the first row I can say for sure that dimension must be greater than $1$. But after that how should I determine the required minimum dimension.
The same question is in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592317/minimum-number-of-dimension) too. But sorry I couldn't follow that hint..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just thinking about the techniques used for solving differential equations, you know that the eigenvalues of the matrix are $\pm 3i$ three times, $2 \pm 3i$, and $0$ twice.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But can you please explain it a little more

Comment: Each time you get an eigenvalue $\lambda$ repeated $n$ times, the solution includes terms of the form $t_k e^{\lambda t}$ for $0 \le k < n$.  So if you see $t^2 \cos(3t) = \frac12 t^2 (e^{3it} + e^{-3it})$, that means $\pm 3i$ must have been eigenvalues three times.

Comment: And the dimension of the system must be at least as large as the number of eigenvalues.  So $\pm 3i$ three times gives a total of 6 eigenvalues.  Now add it all up.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: And thank you for getting me to 20,000 reputation!